# Como informar de quem uma classe se vai estender em tempo de execução?

Tags: java, java-ee, classes, java-8

Tenho a classe

```
public class Conhecimento{}
```

Essa classe se estende de uma outra classe "CteProc"

Só que essa classe CteProc tem "versões" exemplo.

v200.CteProc

v300.CteProc

Meu problema é que na criação da classe Conhecimento preciso informar se ele vai se estender da CteProc 200 ou CteProc 300 de acordo com a versão que recebo. 
Queria saber se é possível fazer isso, alterar o extends ou deixar dynamic.

Comment: Criar classe em tempo de execução?

Comment: Não, as classes já existem, só quero informar de quem uma classe vai se estender em tempo de execução.

Comment: Não tem como, se a classe já está escrita, como você vai alterar após compilado, isso aparentemente é impossivel. Pensei que você queria escrever a classe em tempo de execução.

Comment: Não entendi. Ou se entendi, é o normal. Se o entendimento for o contrário do que estou pensando, aí não dá e nem faria sentido. Se esclarecer, talvez colocar um exemplo, tento comentar melhor ou responder. É isto o que o Articuno está dizendo? Talvez tenha como criar um padrão de projeto.

Comment: Irei editar a pergunta.

Comment: Se quer fazer isso é melhor usar só _generics_, não faz muito sentido em usar herança assim.

Comment: Seria melhor se explicasse qual é o problema que quer resolver.

Comment: É, parece gambiarra e deve ter outra forma de resolver isso, faça o que o ramaral disse.

Comment: @bigown se não entendi errado, me parece que ele quer alterar a herança em "tempo de execução". Isso não seria o mesmo que "reescrever a classe"? Me parece algo meio impossivel, já que na execução, a classe já está compilada.

Comment: @Articuno parece erro de arquitetura, se tem duas classes para serem herdadas, devem existir duas classes herdadas, simples assim, mas se o problema for outro aí pode ter uma solução, pode ser caso de composição, talvez usando um *pattern*  específico.

Comment: Esse 'de acordo com versão que vc recebe'. Vc recebe como? O que define  que será uma ou outra? E qual a diferença de uma pra outra? Os métodos de ambas as classes são os mesmos porém com execuções diferentes?  Me parece que vc esta querendo usar herança e polimorfismo. Mas tá faltando um entendimento de como funciona aí não consegue encaixar no seu problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível uma classe, numa determinada altura, herdar de A e em outra altura herdar de B.

Se eu entendi bem o que pretende, use uma destas abordagens:

- [Bridge Design Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/bridge)

  Se as classes v200.CteProc e v300.CteProc implementam uma mesma interface(CteProc), ou seja as duas classes tem os mesmos métodos mas com implementações diferentes.

  Implemente a classe Conhecimento de forma a receber um objecto de uma classe que implemente a interface CteProc.

  De acordo "com a versão que recebo" você passa um objecto v200.CteProc ou v300.CteProc.

  Internamente, a classe Conhecimento, usa os métodos da interface cuja implementação é dada pelo objecto passado.
- [Adapter Design Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter)

  Se as classes v200.CteProc e v300.CteProc não implementam uma mesma interface, ou seja as duas classes tem métodos diferentes(nomes ou assinaturas).

  Extraia uma interface a partir da classe Conhecimento.

  Escreva duas classes que implementem essa interface: v200.Conhecimento e v300.Conhecimento.

  Para o processamento, a classe v200.Conhecimento usará internamente um objecto v200.CteProc e a v300.Conhecimento um v300.CteProc.

  De acordo "com a versão que recebo" você usa um objecto v200.Conhecimento ou v300.Conhecimento.

  Os clientes da antiga classe Conhecimento deverão passar a referenciar a interface.